# How can I insert a sequence of Strings (not a complex object) to a table using Dapper?

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

All of the examples I have found on here refer to inserting a sequence of a class using the following syntax:

```
var people = new[] 
{ 
    new Person { Age = 1, Name = "Foo" }, 
    new Person { Age = 2, Name = "Bar" }
};

await conn.Execute("INSERT INTO People (Age, Name) VALUES (@Age, @Name)", people);
```

However I need to insert a sequence of *Strings* e.g.

```
var stuff = new[] {"A", "B", ... }; 
await conn.Execute("INSERT INTO someTable (Entry) VALUES (@stuff)", stuff);
```

The above does not work, what syntax should I be using?

Comment: Try `stuff.Select(s => new { Stuff = s })` so you'll have a collection of objects with properties that match your parameter.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that as my sequence is quite large (billions of records) I guess I will have to avoid dapper and use prepared statements instead.

Comment: You should try it and test if it works and what the performance is before rejecting it out of hand.

Comment: Like I said allocating a billion times once for each record is going to cause _GC_ pauses I cannot afford on our servers so yes definitely not a good solution.

Comment: The other option would be something like `new { Stuff = stuff }` but I'm not 100% sure it will unwind the collection into multiple calls.  But really if you have millions of records you should be looking into a bulk insert solution vs. using Dapper.

Comment: The DB I am using is SQLite so when it comes to bulk loading, the above _INSERT_ inside a transaction is the fastest you get can minus the allocation due to the projection, I have solved this now by using prepared statements instead of _Dapper_.

Comment: I guess you did answer the question with regards to the syntax problem and thank you for that but at the end it turned out _Dapper_ is not a good solution for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Since you sequence is really large, I would do everything using a bulk load technique for maximum performances. Just use SqlBulkCopy class:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx

The others option are

1) using Table Valued Parameters, supported by Dapper natively: https://medium.com/dapper-net/sql-server-specific-features-2773d894a6ae

2) Create single JSON with all of your data (or maybe, even better, create several JSON document to mimic a batched load) and use the native JSON support of SQL Server 2016+ to do the job.

just keep in mind that if you just want really good peformances the only way is the SqlBulkCopy option

Comment: @You are assuming the _DBMS_ I am using is _SQLServer_. _Dapper_ works by hanging off _IDbConnection_ therefore it's _DB_ agnostic. In my case here, using prepared statements was the best solution.

Comment: @MaYaN yep, you're right, I was assuming that you were using SQL Server.